# How do you bootstrap Apache NiFi 1.3.0 with a set of DNs

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm doing an install of Apache NiFi 1.3.0... It has a new way to install users, it appears to be only via the GUI.

I'm curious if there's a way to boostrap a list of users by DN with policies set to them.  I know there's the legacy users file...

I'm looking at the users.xml file.  It requires an identifier which maps to policies found in the authorizations.xml file.

Old NiFi would have had me do it here: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/886/securing-nifi-step-by-step.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are several resources which explain how to setup a new secure instance:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#authorizers-setup

https://pierrevillard.com/2016/11/29/apache-nifi-1-1-0-secured-cluster-setup/

https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/17/apache-nifi-1-0-0-authorization-and-multi-tenancy

Comment: Looks like the method used to add users in all those links require an admin to bootstrap himself, then manually add each of the following users.

Comment: Ah maybe I mis-understood the question... you can only bootstrap the initial admin or the legacy users, after that you could script the creation of additional users through the REST API and you would have to authenticate as the initial admin

Comment: The REST API sounds perfect - a quick google search turned them up: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

Comment: I'm using a file-provider for authentication, so not username/pass or kerberos.  I don't see an endpoint to get a token for a secure nifi with a cert and a dn.

Comment: If you have a client certificate for the initial admin, then you don't need a token, you can just use the client certificate on each request, how to do that will be different depending on how you are making the REST calls

Comment: Well that's gotten me further.. I can do the GETs on the user endpoints, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how much of UserEntity I need to post to create a user.

Comment: An easy way to figure it out is to get a running secure instance in Chrome and open Dev Tools, then create a user/group/policy and look at each request that NiFi UI made to the server.

Comment: Yea.. Trial/Error... This is what worked for me: Component with only Identity as a DN and a revision with version of 0.  I added permissions, but it wasn't required.